# make EditText lose focus

Tags: android

I have two EditText fields in my activity and a done button. I want both the EditText fields to loose focus (that is the cursor should not not be displayed on either of them) when the user presses the button. I am using the following code:

```
private OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            tv1.clearFocus();
            tv2.clearFocus();
            saveButton.requestFocus();

}

}
```

However, when I press the done button, the cursor comes up on `tv1` even if I haven't clicked on any EditText yet. How can I make the EditText fields loose focus on the click of the button

Answer (score 1):

Go to your XML code and remove the attribute `<requestFocus/>` from the EditText.
It should work fine then.

And in case it doesn't, try putting the code to remove the focus as soon as you start the Activity, i.e. inside `onCreate()` itself, so that when you click the "done" button, the Activity does not render the focus to anyone by default.

Comment: I don't have `requestFocus` in my xml. When I start my activity, the focus is not on any field. The focus only appears after I click the button

Comment: And what do you intend to do once the Done button is pressed ? Refresh the activity ?

Comment: it just performs some action - shows a dialog box including the text written by user in the `EditText` field

Comment: So, you are saying that when you dismiss the dialog box, the EditText gains focus ?

Comment: yeah. Always the first one. Even if I click on the button without changing anything in edittext

Comment: Did you try putting the code to remove the focus from the EditText in onCreate ? Of after dialog.dismiss() is called ?

Comment: yeah. I did. I even tried using a code that would clear the focus from the EditText if user clicked anywhere else on screen. This worked when user touches anywhere but the button. If the user touches the button, the focus stays, otherwise, its lost. Weird!

Comment: EditText1 would always take the focus because I guess it is the first view in your layout, so the focus goes to it by default when the dialog is dismissed. Try calling `saveButtonrequestFocus()` after dialog.dismiss() is called.

Comment: What about making an invisible view in your layout and run a thread to set the request to it always ? Not a very ethical solution, but this workaround can work for you.